# The p-adic valuation of the sequnce $nc_n=c_{n-1}+c_{n-p}$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. While I am proving the convergence of a series expansion defined by 
$$
\mathfrak{F}(x)=\exp(\pi (x-x^p))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (\pi x)^n
$$
over $\mathbb{C}_p$, where $\pi^{p-1}=-p$ and $c_n$ is defined by the recurrence relation
$$
c_0=1, c_{-p}=\cdots=c_{-1}=0, nc_n=c_{n-1}+c_{n-p},
$$
I found that the convergence of the series on the disk of radius $1+\epsilon>1$ is equivalent to the fact that the p-adic valutation of the sequence $c_n$ is smaller than or equal to 1. I tried some evaluation for $c_n$ when $p=7$ but the numerator gets uncontrollable as $n$ gets larger. It must be enough to prove for the case when $p$ divides $n$, but even when $p=n$, this claim seems nontrivial since $p$ divides $(p-1)!+1$, which is obviously true by some theorems from group and field theory, but the proof seems quite nontrivial and impossible to applicate for the general case.

Is my approach even correct? I doubt if the proof must be the opposite way: proving the convergence of the series implies that the p-adic valuation for the sequence is smaller than or equal to 1. Please give me any hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think one should try to advance in $p$-adic number theory if one finds a proof for $(p-1)! \equiv -1$ (mod $p$) too nontrivial to use. That being said, well, to go the other way around, what do you allow to use about 1) the convergence radius of exp, and about 2) how convergence radii change under variable substitutions like $x \mapsto \pi(x-x^p)$? It seems like one can conclude from those things, but what if you find them too nontrivial too?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Is it? I know that the radius of convergence of the exponential is $p^{-1/(p-1)}$, and multiplying $\pi$ increases the radius to 1, but I don't see why putting $x-x^p$ increases the radius.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg And I know that proving that $p$ divides $(p-1)!+1$ is an easy exercise, and I can handle it myself, but I didn't feel that the proof is related in anyway with the definition of the sequence. I also tried the case $n=2p$, and it was possible to prove that $p^2$ divides the numerator, which looks very ugly, but I couldn't see any rules or anything I can apply to the general case.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg The function is defined by the power series of $\exp(\pi(x-x^p))$, and not the function $\exp(\pi(x-x^p))$ itself, and I doubt the radius of convergence of the function $\exp(\pi(x-x^p))$ is actually $1$, so plugging in $x-x^p$ gives no help to find the radius of the convergence of the power series. The p-adic norm of $x-x^p$ must be same as that of $x$, so p-adic norm of $x-x^p$ being smaller than 1 is equivalent to $|x|_p<1$, and the radius really does not increase, I think. This is the reason why I tried to find the p-adic norm for the coefficient. Or am I wrong  here?

Comment: I see. Sorry if my inital comment sounded condescending. -- So how do you know that the statement is even correct, i.e. that the series converges on a disk of radius $1+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$ (I assume that's what you want to show)?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg That's from the literature, although it is not presenting the proof, so I believe it must be true.